# how to add new field in mongodb using java

Tags: java, arrays

Using Java code I need to add new field name in mongo db. While updating code I add new column name.

```java
public JSONObject addbeneficiaryCode() {        
    JSONArray jsonArrResult = new JSONArray();
    ((List<JSONObject>)ObjectRepository.INSTANCE.get(new JSONObject()
            .add(QUERY, new JSONObject()
                .add(OBJECT_NAME, ObjectName.MASTER)
            )
            .add(PROJECT, new JSONArray()
                    .add(DATA)
                    .add("_id")
                    .add("code")
            )
    )).forEach(j->{

        JSONObject json = j;    

        json.add("new_code", code+"-1");

        ObjectRepository.INSTANCE.update(new JSONObject()
                .add(QUERY, new JSONObject()
                    .add(_ID,j.getString("_id"))
                    .add(OBJECT_NAME, ObjectName.MASTER)
                .add(SET, new JSONObject()
                         .add("new_code",code+"-1")
                        )
        );
    });
    return null;
}

ObjectRepository.INSTANCE.update(new JSONObject()
                    .add(QUERY, new JSONObject()
                        .add(_ID,j.getString("_id"))
                        .add(OBJECT_NAME, ObjectName.MASTER)
                        )
                    .add(SET, new JSONObject()
                            .add("new_code",code+"-1")

                            )
            );
```

The output I want to display is:

```
{
    _id : ObjectId("5d5ff2c6bdba954eacaca632")
    code: 13244
    new_code: 13244-1
}
```

The actual data in Mongo db is:

```
{
    _id : ObjectId("5d5ff2c6bdba954eacaca632")
    code: 13244
}
```

Here I want to add new field new_code. While I am adding new_code I am getting unknown sources as an internal server error.